# How to parse languages other than English with Stanford Parser？ in java, not command lines

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I have been trying to use Stanford Parser in my Java program to parse some sentences in Chinese. Since I am quite new at both Java and Stanford Parser, I used the 'ParseDemo.java' to practice. The code works fine with sentences in English and outputs the right result. However, when I changed the model to 'chinesePCFG.ser.gz' and tried to parse some segmented Chinese sentences, things went wrong.

Here's my code in Java

```java
class ParserDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel("edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/chinesePCFG.ser.gz");
    if (args.length > 0) {
      demoDP(lp, args[0]);
    } else {
      demoAPI(lp);
    }
  }

  public static void demoDP(LexicalizedParser lp, String filename) {
    // This option shows loading and sentence-segment and tokenizing
    // a file using DocumentPreprocessor
    TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
    GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();
    // You could also create a tokenier here (as below) and pass it
    // to DocumentPreprocessor
    for (List<HasWord> sentence : new DocumentPreprocessor(filename)) {
      Tree parse = lp.apply(sentence);
      parse.pennPrint();
      System.out.println();

      GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parse);
      Collection tdl = gs.typedDependenciesCCprocessed(true);
      System.out.println(tdl);
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  public static void demoAPI(LexicalizedParser lp) {
    // This option shows parsing a list of correctly tokenized words
    String sent[] = { "我", "是", "一名", "学生" };
    List<CoreLabel> rawWords = Sentence.toCoreLabelList(sent);
    Tree parse = lp.apply(rawWords);
    parse.pennPrint();
    System.out.println();

    TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
    GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();
    GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parse);
    List<TypedDependency> tdl = gs.typedDependenciesCCprocessed();
    System.out.println(tdl);
    System.out.println();

    TreePrint tp = new TreePrint("penn,typedDependenciesCollapsed");
    tp.printTree(parse);
  }

  private ParserDemo() {} // static methods only
}
```

It's basically the same as ParserDemo.java, but when I run it I get the following result:

> Loading parser from serialized file
>   edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/chinesePCFG.ser.gz ... done [2.2
>   sec]. (ROOT   (IP
>       (NP (PN 我))
>       (VP (VC 是)
>         (NP
>           (QP (CD 一名))
>           (NP (NN 学生))))))
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to
>   invoke public
>   edu.stanford.nlp.trees.EnglishGrammaticalStructure(edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.trees.GrammaticalStructureFactory.newGrammaticalStructure(GrammaticalStructureFactory.java:104)
>     at parserdemo.ParserDemo.demoAPI(ParserDemo.java:65)    at
>   parserdemo.ParserDemo.main(ParserDemo.java:23)

the code on line 65 is:

```
 GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parse);
```

My guess is that chinesePCFG.ser.gz misses something relevant to 'edu.stanford.nlp.trees.EnglishGrammaticalStructure'. Since the parser parses Chinese correctly via commandlines, there must be something wrong with my own code. I have been searching, only to find few similar cases some of which mentioned about using the right model, but I don't really know how to modify the code to the 'right model'. Hope that someone could help me with it. I am a newbie on Java and Stanford Parser, so please be specific. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the GrammaticalStructureFactory is constructed from a `PennTreebankLanguagePack`, which is for the English Penn Treebank.  You need to use (in two places)

```
TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new ChineseTreebankLanguagePack();
```

and to import this appropriately

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.international.pennchinese.ChineseTreebankLanguagePack;
```

But we also generally recommend using the factored parser for Chinese (since it works considerably better, unlike for English, although at the cost of more memory and time usage)

```
LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel("edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/chineseFactored.ser.gz");
```

Comment: Thank you！ That works perfectly. Also, thanks for the advice about using the factored parser. I really learned alot.